# Bring variable value from Block Scope to use in Global Scope as a simple Variable - JAVASCRIPT. In FIRESTORE

Tags: javascript, firebase, function, google-cloud-firestore, global-variables

I'm creating an App in Firebase, using FireStore as my Database.

In the code below, I create a variable `order` and assign it a value of 1.

Then I update the value to the number 4 and `console.log` it to check. Which turns out fine.

But when I log the variable after the function, to cross-check, it returns 1 again, instead of the updated value(i.e. 4).

> **I want to use the value I'm getting from the database, in the global**
>   **namespace. (use it simply in my JS code outside this function.)**

**This is My code** (do See the  //comments)

```js
    console.log("Value initiated : " + order); // logs 'Value initiated : 1'

    //A function that gets another value from the FireStore Database and assigns it to the variable.
    function getField() {
      db.collection("index")
        .doc("artNum")
        .get()
        .then(function(doc) {
          order = doc.data().artNum; //I reassign the variable to '4' here.
          console.log("Value assigned : " + order); // logs 'Value assigned : 4'
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    }

    getField(); 
    console.log("Updated Value : " + order); // (to crosscheck) logs " Updated Value : 1 " but should be equal to 4
```

I've been into JS for only a month, I'm quite a beginner. Some of the solutions I thought-&-tried were.

1. Use `order` variable outside the function straight-away, like I did above, which didn't work.
2. Assign the value of `order` to a new variable in the global namespace, which didn't work either.

**I want to use this value outside in my global namespace.**

Basically, I want to use the `order` variable outside, in my code. Also, I'll use this variable again, for naming other documents in my Firestore Database. In simple terms, It's necessary for me to have this value as a simple global `var` variable in my script.

> Please help me with what I'm doing wrong or what this code is missing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: No, my friend, It doesn't. Basically I'm a newbie in web development, and of course Javascript. And I'm not able to integrate this in my code. Can you please update my code with this method. I'll be really thankful.

Comment: I'm on mobile, so not able update your code atm.  But basically return your promise `return db.collection....`,. And the do `getfield.then(..`

Comment: Thw problem with your code is not about scope but about **timing**. The last line will execute before the variable is set. So, your code does bring the value successfully into global scope. Without knowing more about what you plan to do with this value it’s hard to provide a specific solution. I recommend to again read the answers in the linked question or provide more information.

Comment: @FelixKling here, have a look at this - [link to image](https://ibb.co/m9YvBvr).